# How to know which part of my code error in syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I don't know what is wrong with my code. i wrotte enough many code. And it says "Syntax Error"

This is the error place when i press F5 or Run > Run Module
[This is the picture that shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEa1b.jpg) it just has **red sign** with ("). No other explanation of why that can be error.

This is some of my code:

```
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.endgame = False
        self.coordinates = None
    def move(self):
        self.animate()
        if self.y < 0:
            self.jump_count += 1
            if self.jump_count > 20:
                self.y = 4
        if self.y > 0:
            self.jump_count -= 1
        co = self.coords()
        left = True
        right = True
        top = True
        bottom = True
        falling = True
        if self.y > 0 and co.y2 >= self.game.canvas_height:
            self.y = 0
            bottom = False
        elif self.y < 0 and co.y1 <= 0:
            self.y = 0
            top = False
        if self.x >  0 and co.x2 >= self.game.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
            right = False
        elif self.x < 0 and co.x1 <= 0:
            self.x = 0
            left = False
        for sprite in self.game.sprites:
            if sprite == self:
                continue
            sprite_co = sprite.coords()
            if top and self.y < 0 and collided_top(co, sprite_co):
                self.y = -self.y
                top = False
            if bottom and self.y > 0 and collided_bottom(self.y, co, sprite_co):
                self.y = sprite_co.y1 - co.y2
                if self.y < 0:
                    self.y = 0
                bottom = False
                top = False
            if bottom and falling and self.y == 0 and co.y2 < self.game.canvas_height and collided_bottom(1, co, sprite_co):
                falling = False
            if left and self.x < 0 and collided_left(co, sprite_co):
                self.x = 0
                left = False
            if right and self.x > 0 and collided_right(co, sprite_co):
                self.x = 0
                right = False
        if falling and bottom and self.y == 0 and co.y2 < self.game.canvas_height:
            self.y = 4
        self.game.canvas.move(self.image, self.x, self.y)

    def coords(self):
        xy = self.game.canvas.coords(self.image)
        self.coordinates.x1 = xy[0]
        self.coordinates.y1 = y1[1]
        self.coordinates.x2 = xy[0] + 27
        self.coordinates.y2 = xy[1] + 30
        return self.coordinates

class PlatformSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, photo_image, x, y, width, height):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.photo_image = photo_image
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')
        self.coordinates = Coords(x, y, x + width, y + height)

class StickFigureSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.images_left = [
            PhotoImage(file="figure.L1.gif"),
            photoImage(file="figure-L2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-L3.gif")
        ]
        self.images_right = [
            PhotoImage(file"figure-R1.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-R2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-R3.gif")
        ]
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(200, 470, image=self.images_left[0], anchor='nw')
        self.x = -2
        self.y = 0
        self.current_image = 0
        self.current_image_add = 1
        self.jump_count = 0
        self.last_time = time.time()
        self.coordinates = Coords()
        game.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        game.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        game.canvas.bind_all('<space>', self.jump)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0
            self.x = 2

    def jump(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0
            self.y = -4
            self.jump_count = 0


     def animate(self):
         if self.x != 0 and self.y == 0:
             if time.time() - self.lats_time > 0.1:
                 self.last_time = time.time()
                 self.current_image += self.current_image_add
                 if self.current_image >= 2:
                     self.current_image_add = -1
                 if self.current_imge <= 0:
                     self.current_image_add = 1
        if self.x < 0:
            if self.y != 0:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.images_left[2])
            else:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.images_left[self.current_image])

            elif self.x > 0:
                if self.y != 0:
                    self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.images_right[2])
            else:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.images_right[self.current_image])
```

And this is the instruction after all of them:

```
sf = StickFigureSprite(g)
g.sprites.append(sf)
```

I just don't know what is wrong. Cause it just says "Syntax Error" without any explanation

Comment: You need `PhotoImage(file = "figure-R1.gif")` instead of `PhotoImage(file"figure-R1.gif"),`

Comment: The traceback will also include the line number

Answer (score 2):

In the screenshot you're missing an equals sign, `=`. You've also apparently not capitalized `PhotoImage` as `photoImage` a few lines above that.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I did not notice that before.